# ESLint: 'Helmet' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using `react-helmet-async` with `webpack.ProvidePlugin`. So I don't need to import this package.

Can I add `Helmet` to ignore list for `react/jsx-no-undef`? Want to do this without eslint comment, because it is used in many files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround:

`.eslintrc`

```
{
  "globals": {
    "Helmet": true
  },
}
```